# How can I copy and paste text lines across different files in a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

From a certain number of files, I need to create a new file where each line of text is the sequence of the respective lines from my original files.
So, let's say I have two files with a structure like this:

File1:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

File2:

```
XXXX
YYYY
ZZZZ
```

I need to combine them to get a result like:

```
AAAAXXXX
BBBBYYYY
CCCCZZZZ
```

How can I do this from a bash script?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`paste`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/paste.1.html) command:

```
paste -d '' File1 File2
```

By default, `paste` joins the lines with tabs, so we need to use the `-d` option to tell it to use the empty string for joining.

Comment: If this answer helps you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

Through [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) way:

```bsh
awk '{getline x<"file2"; print $0x}' file1
```

- `getline x<"file2"` reads the entire line from *file2* and holds into **x** variable.
- `print $0x` prints the whole line from *file1* by using `$0` then `x` which is the saved line of *file2*.

Answer (score 1):

[`paste`](https://askubuntu.com/a/840908/216503) is the way to go, but for the sake of completeness here is a `bash` focused solution (with little help from `seq`, and `wc`):

```
for _ in $(seq 1 $(wc -l <f1.txt)); do \
            read -u 3 one; read -u 4 two; echo "${one}${two}"; done 3<f1.txt 4<f2.txt
```

Here we are sending the contents of files `f1.txt`, and `f2.txt` via file descriptors 3, and 4. `read` reads from the respective FDs, and `echo` prints the output in desired format.

The iteration will stop after the `f1.txt` ends, here `_` is a throwaway variable.

---

Better, just `bash`, depending on `read`'s exit status when the EOF is reached, with a `while` construct (thanks to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)):

```
while IFS= read -ru3 one && IFS= read -ru4 two; do echo "${one}${two}"; done 3<f1.txt 4<f2.txt
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat f1.txt
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

$ cat f2.txt
XXXX
YYYY
ZZZZ

$ for _ in $(seq 1 $(wc -l <f1.txt)); do read -u 3 one; read -u 4 two; echo "${one}${two}"; done 3<f1.txt 4<f2.txt
AAAAXXXX
BBBBYYYY
CCCCZZZZ

$ while IFS= read -ru3 one && IFS= read -ru4 two; do echo "${one}${two}"; done 3<f1.txt 4<f2.txt
AAAAXXXX
BBBBYYYY
CCCCZZZZ
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like `while IFS= read -ru3 a && IFS= read -ru4 b; do printf '%s%s\n' "$a" "$b"; done 3<File1 4<File2` terminate naturally upon exhaustion of either file (without requiring help from `seq` or `wc`)?

Comment: @steeldriver It certainly would, edited, thanks for this one.